# Cannot invoke add(char) on the array type char[]

Tags: java, list, arraylist, char, character

```
public static void Reverse(char[] val){
    char[] ch = val;
    for (int g = val.length - 1; g >= 0; g--) {
        ch.add(val[g]);
    }
```

I get an error saying I cannot add characters to the char list, but doesn't a char list only contain characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
//if you really want no side effects for the source array and no return:

public static void reverse(char[] value){
    char[] ch = new char[value.length];
    int i=value.length-1;

    for(var c:value){
        ch[i--]=c;
    }
}

// if you want to do an in place reverse of the passed-in array:

public static void reverse2(char[] value){
    int l=value.length-1;

    for(int i=0; i<l/2; i++){
        char c = value[i];
        value[i]=value[l-i];
        value[l-i]=c;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array is not a list. `char[]` is array. Arrays have fixed size, so you can't add element to them or remove elements from them. If you want to use lists, modify your code:

```java
public static void Reverse(List<Character> val){
    List<Character> ch = val;
    for (int g = val.size() - 1; g >= 0; g--) {
        ch.add(val.get(g));
    }
```

Comment: Can I switch elements around in an array?

Comment: Hey @javax, you can switch using the [add method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) of List. A List is similar to an Array but mainly used for automatically expanding the array size, so if your only intention is to swap elements, I suggest you ask another question.